# How can I get the workbook file name i.e. excel file name

Tags: apache-poi, xssf

I am working on an existing .xlsx file. Can any one share with me that, how can I get my current file name?

I mean, suppose I am working on test.xlsx file. How can I get the name of workbook "test.xlsx" using apache poi.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

POI can open a workbook from any `InputStream` you care to throw at it. (Files are [lower memory](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream), but you can use a stream if you want, and many people do). If a stream isn't file backed, then it doesn't have a filename, so no amount of pleading with POI will get you one!

If you are opening a Workbook from a File, then that `File` object knows the filename. Ask that for it! Otherwise, if opening from an `InputStream`, there most likely isn't a filename, so there's nothing to supply.

Finally, be aware that unlike the name of a Sheet, which is stored in the file, the name of the file itself isn't something magic. Take `test.xls`, copy it to `test2.xls`, and also store it in a database blob field. Load all. All of them are the same file, but two of them have different filenames, and one has no filename at all!

Answer (score -1):

I solved this by storing the file name in class field variable